# How to embed a video from json data within webview in react native?

Tags: react-native, webview, video-streaming, jsx

Hello all I'm trying to embed a video within `WebView` of react native.The url of video will be fetched from json response.But when I tried like the following I got this error

[image]

Following is my code

```
 fetch(GLOBAL.VIDEO_URL + this.props.navigation.state.params.id, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': token
                }
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseData) =>
                    this.setState({
                        section: responseData.data.video_url

                    })

                );

.....
....
 <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 10 }}>

                        <WebView
                            source={{ uri: this.state.section }}
                            javaScriptEnabled={true}
                        />
                    </View>
```

The json response will be the following

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 8631,
        "post_title": "Video Unit 1",
        "post_content": "</p>\n",
        "vedio_url": [
            "xxxxxx"       ]
    }
}
```

Please help me to find a solution.Any help would be really appreciable.Thank you.

Comment: video_url is containing into array, So you need to setState like responseData.data.video_url[0] into responseData block

Comment: No still I'm getting the same error.Is there any way to do this using any other npm ?

Comment: put static video url for testing. is it working or not?

Comment: Yes it is coming. But the video from server response is not coming over there.